# rosserial install with fuerte?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Been trying to install rosserial with fuerte. Following the instructions here. http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup
BTW, someone needs to add a sudo to the first command. Took me about 10 minutes to figure that out.

when I run rosmake rosserial_arduino I get this:

mkdir: cannot create directory `build': Permission denied

I tried chmod'ing the rosserial_arduino folder to 777 to see if that would fix it and it didn't. Any ideas.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36183/rosserial-install-with-fuerte?/) by [punching](https://answers.ros.org/users/1882/punching/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to build rosserial_arduino.

Just copy the ros_lib folder from /rosserial/rosserial_arduino/libraries into your Arduino 'sketchbook' folder (or alternatively the /arduino/examples folder).

After you've done that, the example sketches will appear at File>sketchbook>ros_lib OR File>Examples>ros_lib on the Arduino IDE.

You can select any one of the example/tutorial sketches and compile/upload them to your board. (Follow the corresponding Tutorial from the wiki.)

P.S. Make sure you've made the following changes:
in ros_lib edit ArduinoHardware.h: replace #include "WProgram.h" with #include "Arduino.h"

---

Originally posted by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) with karma: 115 on 2012-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2